# Use Excel VBA to Change View

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a simple `For Each` loop to change the view in Excel, but keep getting a:

> 438 Run-time Error

```
Sub ChangeView()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Select
    ActiveWindow = xlNormalView
    Range("A1").Select
Next
```

The error highlights the `ActiveWindow` line. Why?

Answer (score 8):

`ActiveWindow` is an *object*, `xlNormalView` is a long/enumerated constant associated with a property of that object. You can't assign the property value to the object itself, instead, assign it to the appropriate property. I believe the correct one would be:

```
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA will set all SELECTED sheets to the same view, same zoom level and same visible area as the active tab:

```
Sub ResetAllSheetPerspectives_OnSelectedSheets()
    'Not working? Are any tabs selected? Only works on selected worksheets.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim dZoom, dView As Double

    lRow = ActiveWindow.ScrollRow
    lCol = ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn
    dZoom = ActiveWindow.Zoom
    dView = ActiveWindow.View

    For Each ws In Application.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = dZoom
        ActiveWindow.View = dView
        Application.Goto ws.Cells(lRow, lCol), True
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Please upvote the below source:

[Setting all selected sheets to same visible area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298471/setting-all-selected-sheets-to-same-visible-area/50298725#50298725)

---

See Also:

[How to run a macro in Excel - support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155)

[Use macros in Excel - WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Macros-in-Excel)

[How to use macros you find online in six easy steps - searchengineland.com](https://searchengineland.com/how-to-use-macros-you-find-online-in-6-easy-steps-137786)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
It won't change the view necessarily but it'll select the appropriate cell as well.